# First homebrewing equipment question

Tags: equipment, keg

I'm looking at a homebrewer's equipment that is getting out of the hobby and I'm getting into the hobby.  I'm wanting to spend my money wisely and while jumping right into all-grain brewing.

Here is a list of the equipment for sale for $300

- 10 gallon mash tun (spigot and supply hose screen works great. Never
  had a problem with grain in wort)
- 5 gallon ball lock (2 years old
  with dual regulator and picnic tap)
- Two PET plastic 6 gallon    fermenters (one plastic carboy and one
  big mouth bubbler)
- Two    stoppers
- Two airlocks
- 5# co2 tank about half full
- Starsan cleaner
- Pbw cleaner
- Carboy brush
- Siphon tube
- Miscellaneous tubing
- 2 smaller copper immersion chillers with tubing

I'm not wanting the PET fermenters, the Mash tun is a diy project with scratches and discoloration in the inside, the wort chillers are diy projects as well.

What price do used keg systems from individuals normally run? and How good is it to invest in diy and used fermenting equipment?

[image: Equipment]
[image: Mash Tun]

Comment: I agree with the responses so far. My thoughts are that the only things that I would buy from the lot are:
* CO2 tank;
* 5 gal Cornelius keg;
* possibly, the mash tun, though it looks marginal; The rest, I would feel better getting new.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to tell if it's a good deal or not without seeing everything. I would suggest making a list and compare to similar used gear on ebay etc.

Edit: honestly don't see $300 there. Here's some new prices.10gal igloo $60, 5gal keg $90-$120, 5# aluminum co2 $90, regulator $60.  As far as the plastics, tubing, fittings a etc I would ditch anyways.

One caution, check the date stamp on the co2 tank, if it's not been tested and certified within 5 years you can't fill it with out a hydro test. Your local welding supply can give you pricing. Some older tanks cannot be filled at all, namely steel tanks with bottom collars or showing any rust. Pitting or dents on aluminium is a scrap too. Image below is a scrap c02 tank.
[image: scrap co2 tank]

Comment: Thanks for the co2 tip.  The only problem is this is mostly diy stuff and I can't really compare on ebay because this is all used equipment.

Comment: I don't see 300$ there either.  Brand new maybe, but used, it could be worth 200$...   I would deal the price.